# How to print output in Source pane of RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a function which prints required output in `R console`, but what I am trying, is to get same output as a source code in a `source pane` of a `RStudio`.

**Sample function -**

```
# Declare params for plumber api script----------------------------------
input <- c("A","B","C")
sample_print <- function(input){

  cat(for (i in length(input):1) {
    cat("\n#' @param",  input[i], sep =" " )
  },
  "\n#* @post /",
  sep = "")

}

sample_print(input)
```

**Output-**

```
> sample_print(input)

#' @param C
#' @param B
#' @param A
#* @post /
```

**Note**- I know its possible to `copy/paste` it. But, I have large output text and I am looking for a feasible method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first save your script in text format and use sink() function.
Please refer to this link
https://www.statmethods.net/interface/io.html

Comment: I know, I can achieve this by using function like `sink`, but, I am looking for some interactive solution, where I can run function from `source pane` and get output in `source pane` itself.

Comment: Let us make a function to solve this problem and then add it to R Studio, I think it will be helpful